# Accept a mixed type tuple in a function without losing type checking

Tags: typescript

```
import encodeParam from './encodeParam'

interface UrlParam<T> {
  name: string
  defaultValue: T
  encode: (value: T) => string | null
  decode: (value: string) => T
}

function buildQueryString<T>(...params: [UrlParam<T>, T][]) {
  const searchParams = new URLSearchParams()

  params.forEach(([param, value]) => {
    const newValue = encodeParam(param, value)

    if (newValue) {
      searchParams.set(param.name, newValue)
    }
  })

  return searchParams.toString()
}

const one: UrlParam<string> = {
  name: 'one',
  defaultValue: '',
  encode: (val) => val,
  decode: (val) => val,
}

const two: UrlParam<number> = {
  name: 'two',
  defaultValue: 0,
  encode: (val) => val.toString(),
  decode: (val) => Number(val),
}

const query = buildQueryString(
  [one, 'foo'],
  [two, 42], // This will not compile because only UrlParam<string> is expected.
)
```

I've written a function called `buildQueryString` to encode a series of query parameters using tuples that contain the definition of the param (`UrlParam`) and the value that should be used. I am struggling to set up the signature of the method to accept a mixed type of `UrlParam<T>`, how could this be accomplished?

This should of course work so that the `[UrlParam<T>, T]` constraint of the tuple is still checked, so no `any` types are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Playground Link**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEsFsAcHsCcAuoCmA7AxrAJigCgIbwGSgBm8spA5AHTDpa6HGTUBQZArpouLGlSYc+IiQA8AFQB8ACi7wANixIAuUAFUlKyFOkAaUADcCirinWSAlOoDOieODQBzUAB9QaLosWgA3uygQaDwKIgKggrKYpC0jCKyJmYoVgDc7AC+7NnsTogo8GQEGCia2jF6-oGeJBag9o4u1bhF3ogAaqbmltXxuOqJXXXWoAC80vUOTq4eXj7NKEx1g8l2Uy5WYxOSmTmIAJ7QpVrRrITg8JWjoADaZacSMoaSoAC66QdH9zrn8LbiAEFUAAPfJobC2UAEND7G6vCbXPy3ADSEEEAGsUPtYGRQADXuoTj8CBdATdkfDQBl0pweBg+AJQAAjLjgRTYACK5ng+wAyutnICQWCIVCYXC5LQpdAYrZCeUziS-oDpJsAkEsGh7PUUEQMAALHSQ65oFAAd00ACUADK83XwA1G2RWbJBGWsWy0MgIACixX1slkN3dJEMSXMr024yqwVAmu1prNnWSYyESx0shDkDDQxd1SC4FxskTyfMavzwVs9sdstoVcQmZitDQtUMJdzFayQQyeaCoXC8EEVb1htriFg-Mazmdu3Y8eQAjqRIqDWmCJjNUgdWoi+o+gWrUUHSG6moe96wn6oBWUYmSX3QVwSwGSVvxlM+6yc4E2sQZtg8oPLoXiQEyBTruqm7bn+sDno+KCHseqygAADA+aYiC+phvkktDjpO0zOuhT6Yder5bKAAByXCgQUN6ftk86gAAjty+ypiybKcmxBEuLI1Q3IuhjUN6sGvOhNwwYYAAsABM4mgCAoCSPq4CQmabK+GgsDIFgMBsqUYEYAQXBVqAAiKOxy6sOIq4uBMakgkc9IoNgtDsHmTHMbJHGsuyXIFHyAr8UEgmmoYACsUURQpSkqY5tj6rA3jYJ4OlxlQ0AGe5LpAA)

The key to typing functions like this is to make sure the generic type can contain all the information needed. With just a `T`, everything gets converted to unions and we lose the ordering. Instead, we can use an array/tuple generic type (which I called `A`) where each entry corresponds to each argument tuple:

```
type UrlParamPair<T> = [ UrlParam<T>, T ];
type UrlParamPairs<A extends any[]> = { [K in keyof A]: UrlParamPair<A[K]> };

function buildQueryString<A extends any[]>(...params: UrlParamPairs<A>) {
    ...
}
```

The `UrlParamPairs` [mapped (array) type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) converts the array of types to the array of tuples, e.g. `UrlParamPairs<[string, number]>` becomes `[ UrlParamPair<string>, UrlParamPair<number> ]`

The type inference for the function call shows this working:

```
function buildQueryString<[string, number]>(
    params_0: UrlParamPair<string>, params_1: UrlParamPair<number>): string
```

Comment: Awesome, this exactly what I needed. Now to figure out how I can do this with an array instead of a spread argument.